# Incluir variável no resultado do json

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, array

```
if($_GET['operacao'] == 'banners'){
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'); 
    $rs = $mysqli->query("SELECT foto AS image FROM banners");
    $registros = mysqli_num_rows($rs);

    $arr = array();
    $url = "http://www.site.com.br/";
    while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) { 
        $arr[] = $row;
    } 

    $json_encode = json_encode($arr); 
    echo $json_encode; 
}
```

Esse código acima gera um json assim:

```
[
  {"image": "freightliner.jpg"},
  {"image": "sailing-ships.jpg"},
  {"image": "taxi-cab.jpg"
  }
]
```

Como fazer para que a URL apareça e fique assim:

```
[
  {"image": "http://www.site.com.br/freightliner.jpg"},
  {"image": "http://www.site.com.br/sailing-ships.jpg"},
  {"image": "http://www.site.com.br/taxi-cab.jpg"
  }
]
```

Comment: Concatene no lado cliente, com javascript, ao invés de fazer issno pelo server com php. Para evitar tráfego de dados e processo desnecessário.

Comment: @DanielOmine Como se faz isso?

Comment: poste o código javascript que lê o resultado do json, caso tenha.

Comment: Estou fazendo assim: ``<div class="galleria image-gallery-size widget uib_w_8 d-margins" data-uib="media/image_gallery" data-ver="0" data-sm-trigger="true" images-json="http://www.site.com.br//testeConexaoMobileJson.php?operacao=banners">``

Comment: não é isso.. poste o script que faz a requisição ajax.  Deve ter aí algum código com algo mais ou menos assim: `$.ajax({ .....` e isso `success: function(response){`.. Essa coisa normalmente fica entre tags javascript. É um troço assim: `<script type="text/javascript">`.  Entendeu? Edita coloca na pergunta. Não coloque aqui no comentário.

Comment: Não uso, pois o arquivo ``testeConexaoMobileJson.php`` gera o json na tela como no formato demostrado no tópico.

Comment: ?? como vc requisita o arquivo testeConexaoMobileJson.php? Afinal, algo tem que requisitar e ler o resultado desse script.

Comment: Assim ``<div class="galleria image-gallery-size widget uib_w_8 d-margins" data-uib="media/image_gallery" data-ver="0" data-sm-trigger="true" images-json="http://www.site.com.br//testeConexaoMobileJson.php?operacao=banners‌​">`` Direto na tag.

Comment: vc já postou isso... Apenas entenda que isso não é suficiente. Deve ter algum plugin jquery, script javascript que lê essa url e faz a requisição.. É isso que vc não está entendendo. Poste o código javascript.

Comment: Amigão, se de fato devesse eu postaria, mas não tem. Vamos deixar essa parte de concatenar, você consegue me ajudar com a parte da ``$url`` aparecer?

Comment: não sou seu "amigão". Sem colaboração de sua parte não há como ajudar. Você parece não querer entender que é preciso requisitar e ler o resultado do json. Isso já comentei mais acima, mas não entendo porque vc insiste em não prestar atenção..

Comment: @DanielOmine, desculpe a expressão, e lamento não poder ter sua ajuda, mas agradeço muito. Tudo de bom para você, mas se desejar me ajudar somente com incluir a URL, será de grande ajuda.

Comment: @DanielOmine por favor, me ajuda com o ``while``, incluir a variável **url**.

Answer (score 1):

É só fazer a **concatenação** das variáveis.

```
$url = "http://www.site.com.br/";
while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) { 
    $arr[] = $url.'/'.$row['image'];
}
```

Na variável `$row`, entre `colchetes` você precisa por o nome da coluna `foto`.

Comment: Deu erro, apareceu assim: ``["http://www.site.com.br//Array","http://www.site.com.br//Array","http://www.site.com.br//Array","http://www.site.com.br//Array","http://www.site.com.br//Array","http://www.site.com.br//Array","http://www.site.com.br//Array"]``

Comment: Atualizei o Poste.

Comment: ``"image": `` não aparece

Comment: Ah mano... Nem vi. Você deu outro nome para a coluna no `SELECT`. Seria `image`ao invés de `foto`.

Comment: Eu sei, já tinha mudado, mesmo assim não aparece.

Comment: Como você está fazendo ? Edita sua pergunta com seu código atual.

Comment: é exatamente como esta no tópico. Só muda sua ultima atualização.

Comment: Esta aparecendo assim ``["http:\/\/www.site.com.br\/670x294.jpg","http:\/\/www.site.com.br\/monte.jpg","http:\/\/www.site.com.br\/girasol.jpg","http:\/\/www.site.com.br\/sol.jpg","http:\/\/www.site.com.br\/sopro.jpg","http:\/\/www.site.com.br\/sol2.jpg","http:\/\/www.site.com.br\/115403.jpg"]``

Comment: tem que aparecer: ``{"image": "http://www.site.com.br/freightliner.jpg"},``

Comment: O modo como apareceu com barras invertidas está correto. Isso são caracteres de escape. ..

Comment: @Zoom Mais alguma sugestão?